# Pandas df.to_json(orient="records")

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert dataframe to Json using `df.to_json(orient="records")` but by doing this it changes **datetime** column to number.

Below is the dataframe data before converting.

```
======================================
    id                   name  is_healthy health_updated_at          created_at
0  203  vsds_anpr4_17_850_rhs       False               NaT 2022-12-13 18:29:00
1  202  vsds_anpr4_17_890_rhs       False               NaT 2022-12-13 18:27:00
2  201  vsds_radar_17_700_rhs       False               NaT 2022-12-13 18:26:00
3  200  vsds_radar_17_300_rhs       False               NaT 2022-12-13 18:23:00
4  199   vsds_anpr4_1_000_rhs       False               NaT 2022-09-12 12:00:00
======================================
```

Below is the data in Json format after converting.

```
[
   {
      "id":203,
      "name":"vsds_anpr4_17_850_rhs",
      "is_healthy":false,
      "health_updated_at":"None",
      "created_at":1670956140000
   },
   {
      "id":202,
      "name":"vsds_anpr4_17_890_rhs",
      "is_healthy":false,
      "health_updated_at":"None",
      "created_at":1670956020000
   },
   {
      "id":201,
      "name":"vsds_radar_17_700_rhs",
      "is_healthy":false,
      "health_updated_at":"None",
      "created_at":1670955960000
   },
   {
      "id":200,
      "name":"vsds_radar_17_300_rhs",
      "is_healthy":false,
      "health_updated_at":"None",
      "created_at":1670955780000
   },
   {
      "id":199,
      "name":"vsds_anpr4_1_000_rhs",
      "is_healthy":false,
      "health_updated_at":"None",
      "created_at":1662984000000
   }
]
```

As you can see the created_at has now converted to number.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default [`df.to_json` uses *epoch* date format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json). But you can control it by using `date_format` argument.

> **date_format**
>
> Type of date conversion. ‘**epoch**’ =
> epoch milliseconds, ‘**iso**’ = ISO8601. The default depends on the
> orient. For orient='table', the default is ‘iso’. For all other
> orients, the default is ‘**epoch**’.

```
df.to_json(orient="records", date_format="iso")
```